# WPF: Dynamic property value in Style

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to use a **PlaceHolder** in a WPF Style that could later be assigned a value by the implementing control? Something like:

```
<Style x:Key="BigButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#58290a" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Lucida Console" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source=[SOME PLACEHOLDER]></Image>
                <TextBlock>[ANOTHER PLACEHOLDER]</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and then a Button could assign an image path to this place-holder like this:

```
<Button Name="btn" Style="{StaticResource BigButton}">
    <SOME CLEVER WAY OF ASSIGNING A PATH TO Style.Content.StackPanel.Image.Source and Style.Content.StackPanel.TextBlock.Text>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [Attached properties](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/helloworld/archive/2010/06/25/understanding-wpf-dependency-property-and-attached-property.aspx).

Create a utility class with you "placeholder properties":

```
public static class BigButtonUtils
{
    public static Uri GetBBImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Uri)obj.GetValue(BBImageProperty);
    }
    public static void SetBBImage(DependencyObject obj, Uri value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BBImageProperty, value);
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BBImage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BBImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BBImage", typeof(Uri), typeof(BigButtonUtils), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    public static string GetBBCaption(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(BBCaptionProperty);
    }
    public static void SetBBCaption(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BBCaptionProperty, value);
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BBCaption.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BBCaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BBCaption", typeof(string), typeof(BigButtonUtils), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Apply those properties on a Button..

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource BigButtonStyle}"
        bb:BigButtonUtils.BBImage="http://programming.enthuses.me/1.png" 
        bb:BigButtonUtils.BBCaption="My caption" />
```

..and use the property values in your Style:

```
<Style x:Key="BigButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#58290a" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Lucida Console" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=(bb:BigButtonUtils.BBImage)}" Stretch="None" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(bb:BigButtonUtils.BBCaption)}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**NOTE:** Don't set any other content on the Button, like `<Button Content="..." />` or `<Button ...>SomeContent</Button>`, as that would override the "placeholder content" from the Style.

Comment: I like that, though I'd prefer to have a XAML-only solution (without the code-behind). Can we build one? Also, being relatively new to WPF, may I ask, do you see any difference between what you're suggesting and what Florian has posted below? Any particular advantage/disadvantage between the two?

Comment: The difference is that the attached properties (`BBImage` and `BBCaption`) don't belong in the code-behind of your `Window` or `UserControl`. You can put the `BigButtonUtils` class (along with `BigButtonStyle`) in a separate project/assembly and use it everywhere. I don't think you'll be able to do what you're looking for without writing _any_ code, but at least this way you only have to write it once, and then apply it to as many buttons as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties as placeholder:

```
    <Style x:Key="BigButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#58290a" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Lucida Console" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Placeholder}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The property:

```
    public string _placeholder;
    public string Placeholder
    {
        get
        {
            return _placeholder;
        }
        set
        {
            _placeholder = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Placeholder");
        }
    }
```

Now you can modify this property when you want, e.g. through a OnClick-EventHandler or a Command.

Comment: Is there a XAML way of doing it (without using the code-behind)? What if I have this style in a ResourceDictionary and want to apply it to 3 Buttons in my Window simply by <Button Style="{StaticResource BigButton}">[XAML code to assign a value to the Style PlaceHolder]</Button>